# Here api speed limit for trucks

Tags: here-api

We're currently using the reverse geocoder to get the speed limit on the road of a specified lat/long position. However that speed limit is always for cars, but we have to consider trucks as well. Anyone knows a way to get the speed limit meant for trucks?

Comment: Doesn't look like the `here-api` provides that information, you could consider comparing the car speed to a table of other modes of transport - [highway code](http://www.highwaycodeuk.co.uk/changes-and-answers/new-higher-speed-limits-for-lorries-in-england-and-wales)

Answer (score 0):

This is offered in the HERE "Platform Data Extension" service: https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/introduction.html

Found a general speed limit example for PHP here (probably you have to adapt the layer to the right one for truck speed limits instead of car speed limits):
https://github.com/seaBass3/here-pde-speed-limit/blob/master/Here_PDE_Demo.php

Comment: Unfortunately PDE is an "Advanced Feature" which isn't available with our subscription. Thanks anyway.